# set Datagrid background as Alternating Background Color

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid ,I want to set its background like Alternating background color ,I set its AlternatingRowBackground to LightGray and AlterntationCount to 2 but the alternating Background effects only on the Grid with Items.I want to display Alternating Background even the datagrid doesnt have items.How to accomplish this.

Here is my DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Height="200" 
                  Width="100"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding OrderRecords}"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource InflowDataGridAlternateBackgroundBrush}"
                  AlternationCount="2"
                  Margin="3,3,3,3"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order #"
                                    Width="100"
                                    Binding="{Binding OrderNo}"
                                    MinWidth="150" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Date"
                                    Width="100"
                                    Binding="{Binding OrderDate}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If datagrid don't have items , it means there are no rows created.So AlternatingRowBackground has no effect.If you want to show this effect without any items,try adding some rows without data.

Comment: Thats not I want ,I want to set Datagrid background with some alternating Background effect,Actually the datagird is binded to an collection in my viewModel which is populated from the database